# Portal for ArcGIS WMTS layers are optimised & un-cacheable

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.3, wmts, arcgis-portal

When a **WMTS in Portal for ArcGIS 10.3.1 is opened** (via Portal) **in an mxd**, the WMTS layer **properties are not standard**. The; Source, Layers, and Advanced tabs are missing. When the portal WMTS layer used as an input into *arcpy.ExportMapServerCache_server()* **it fails without any errors.**

I've discovered that if you copy and paste the layer into the same data frame, the layer regains all of it's normal properties. I think the portal extracted layer is actually put in a hidden optimized base map layer.

I need to use ArcPy to cache this service locally as a part of a greater user workflow. However beofre I proceed I need a method to handle this "optimized portal WMTS layer".. *Has anyone experienced this* and then figured out a way around it?

[image]

Comment: PolyGeo when you are QAQC'ing the tags can you add the new tag  "arcgis-10.3.1"

Comment: I just added [tag:ArcGIS-10.3.1] as a synonym of [tag:ArcGIS-10.3].  This maintains the current consensus on any finer-grained tags than that being unnecessary for ArcGIS platform questions - see http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3131/using-tags-on-arcgis-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking with Esri Inc technical support we discovered that this is a "feature". All layers coming out of Portal are wrapped in something special. This wrapper changes layers to "unsupported" for many things inducing touching them with ArcPy.